# pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates.move_to_front() does not work

Tags: python, pygame

So I am tring to use pygame to develop a game. I want my cursor image to be on the top layer. I've tried this:

```
pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates.move_to_front(cursor_img).
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/PythonProjects/pythonProjects/game/main.py", line 50, in <module>
    pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates.move_to_front(cursor_img)
TypeError: move_to_front() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sprite'
```

I think it also wants me to pass in the 'self' argument but I don't know what to pass into it.
Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates) is a *Group* object that manages [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects.
[`pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates.move_to_front`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates.move_to_front) is a [Method Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects). The argument of `pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates.move_to_front` must be a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects contained in the *Group*:

> Brings the sprite to front, changing sprite layer to topmost layer

Therefore you must create a *Group*

```py
layered_group = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
```

That contains [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects. In the following `my_sprite` is a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) object:

```py
layered_group.layered_group.add(my_sprite)
```

Then you can associate a sprite to a layer and bring the layer to the front:

```py
cursor_layer = 1
layered_sprites.change_layer(my_sprite, cursor_layer)
layered_group.move_to_front(my_sprite)
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

obstacle = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
obstacle.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
obstacle.image.fill((128, 128, 128))
obstacle.rect = obstacle.image.get_rect(center = (140, 140))

player = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
player.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
player.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
player.rect = obstacle.image.get_rect(center = (160, 160))

layered_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates([player, obstacle])
layered_sprites.change_layer(player, 1)
layered_sprites.change_layer(obstacle, 2)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                layered_sprites.move_to_front(player)
            if event.button == 3:
                layered_sprites.move_to_front(obstacle)

    window.fill(0)
    layered_sprites.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```