# Why is my layered updates not working on my sprites?

Tags: pygame, sprite

I haver tried updating and drawing the `layered_group` but still deos not work. I have read a couple of tutorials and as far as I can tell my following code should work but I am missing something...

these are the groups and instances...

```
self.layered_group = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()

    self.visible_sprites = CameraGroup(self.current_level)
    self.active_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    self.obstacle_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

    self.exit_sprite_1 = pygame.sprite.Group()

for style, layout in layouts.items():
        for row_index, row in enumerate(layout):
            for col_index, col in enumerate(row):
                if col != '-1':
                    x = col_index * TILESIZE
                    y = row_index * TILESIZE

                    if style == 'blocks':
                        Tile((x,y), [self.visible_sprites, self.obstacle_sprites], 'tile')

                    if style == 'entrances':
                        if col == str(self.entry_pos):
                            self.player = Player((x, y), [self.visible_sprites, self.active_sprites, self.layered_group], self.obstacle_sprites, self.layered_group, 1)
                    
                        
                    if style == 'exits':
                        if col == '1':
                            sprite = ExitDoor((x,y - TILESIZE // 2), [self.visible_sprites, self.active_sprites], self.layered_group,0, 'door')
                            self.exit_sprite_1.add(sprite)
```

And in the class....

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, pos, groups, obstacle_sprites, layered_group, layer):
    self._layer = layer,
    super().__init__(groups)
```

run method only updates the visible sprite group as below, is this why? My print troubleshooting shows all ordered correctly when spawned on each level and it runs. Do I have to incorporate this `self.layered_group` into my run method? If so I am struggling as everything is in visible group!!

```
def run(self):
    self.layers_group.update()
    print(self.layers_group.layers())
    if self.game_paused:
        self.pause.run()
    else:
        self.input()
        self.active_sprites.update()
        self.visible_sprites.offset_draw(self.player)
```

Comment: Why `self._layer = layer,`? Why the `,`?

Comment: typo, not like this in code.

Comment: and I have renamed layered_group to layers_group but same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can the layer the *Sprite* in a `LayeredUpdates` *Group* is associated with `change_layer` change:

```py
layered_group = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
```

```py
layered_group.change_layer(sprite, layer)
```

However, the *Sprites* are only drawn in the correct order if you call `draw` on the `LayeredUpdates` Group_ object. Adding *Sprites* to a `LayeredUpdates` *Group*, don't magically change the order of the *Spirtes* in another *Group*. You have to call

```py
layered_group.draw(screen)
```

See also [pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates.move_to_front() does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69365433/pygame-sprite-layeredupdates-move-to-front-does-not-work/69365563#69365563)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. As the player is passed into the draw method of the camera group class, I could seperate the player from all other sprites and blit the player after the others as follows... let me know if this can be tidied!

```
for sprite in self.sprites():
        if sprite != player:
            offset = sprite.rect.topleft - self.offset
            self.display_surf.blit(sprite.image, offset)

    for sprite in self.sprites():
        if sprite == player:
            offset = sprite.rect.topleft - self.offset
            self.display_surf.blit(sprite.image, offset)
```